# How to turn on the expanded mode in Oracle SQL*Plus?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, sqlplus

As in the switch `\x` of PostgreSQL.

For more information on the PostgreSQL expanded mode, fetch https://serverfault.com/questions/618642/psql-expanded-mode-equivalency-for-mysql.

Both PostgreSQL and MySQL have mechanisms for getting an expanded mode, I guess Oracle should have it too.

I am using the instant client 11.2 by the way.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You want to show each row individually with 1 column per line?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ that is what \x does in Postgres

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4845523000346615725

Comment: not in SQL*Plus, but here's how to do it in SQLcl http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2016/09/extending-oracle-sql-developer-command-line-sqlcl-with-javascript-single-record-viewer/