# Equivalent in SQL*Plus of sqlite3's "line mode"

Tags: sqlplus

One of the output display modes supported by the default sqlite3 text client is the so-called "line mode".  In this mode, the output of `SELECT` queries is displayed "one value per line".  Here's an example:

```
sqlite> .mode line
sqlite> SELECT * FROM invoices LIMIT 2;
        InvoiceId = 1
       CustomerId = 2
      InvoiceDate = 2009-01-01 00:00:00
   BillingAddress = Theodor-Heuss-Straße 34
      BillingCity = Stuttgart
     BillingState = 
   BillingCountry = Germany
BillingPostalCode = 70174
            Total = 1.98

        InvoiceId = 2
       CustomerId = 4
      InvoiceDate = 2009-01-02 00:00:00
   BillingAddress = Ullevålsveien 14
      BillingCity = Oslo
     BillingState = 
   BillingCountry = Norway
BillingPostalCode = 0171
            Total = 3.96
```

How can I achieve the same thing with SQL*Plus?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/166551/48347

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4845523000346615725 - credits to Jack Douglas Moderator Diamond at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166551